# how to accelerate the training of RPN or SSD neuron network

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

We know that in SSD, there are three output feature maps. During training, I have to caculate the loss between the output of the SDD and the ground truth every pixel. So how can I complete this "from pixel to pixel operation" quickly? Now I use the nested for loop to complete the caculation of loss, but it is extremely slow. Say another example, there is an output map indicating the probability whether there is an object or not, say the size is 100×100, and I set the threshould 0.5. So how can I know which pixel of the output map has a value above 0.5? Now I use the for loop, like `for i in range(100): for y in range(100): if map[i][y]>0.5  do something`,it is too slow! So how can I solve it?

Comment: Could you provide more information, maybe a bit of code, about the "pixel to pixel" operation performed in your loss function?

Answer (score 0):

Given the information in your question, you could use the [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/contents.html) library to work with [`numpy.ndarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html), you would then be able to perform a wide range of element-wise operations without the need for loops.

For instance, with `map` a 2d `numpy.ndarray`, `map > 0.5` returns a boolean array of the same size as `map`, indicating which elements are greater than 0.5. You could then use this to perform your computations only with the relevant elements.